# Google Play web scraping: how can you get the number of votes for each review in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-play, rstudio

I'm doing web scraping in R of the reviews of a Google Play app, but I can't get the number of votes. I indicate the code: ***likes <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".xjKiLb") %>% html_attr("aria-label")*** and I get no value. How can it be done?

**Get scrape votes**

[image]

**FULL CODE**

```
#Loading the rvest package
library(rvest)
library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of 


url <- 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gospace.parenteral&showAllReviews=true'

# starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

# go to website
remDr$navigate(url)

# get page source and save it as an html object with rvest
html_obj <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()

likes <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".xjKiLb") %>% html_attr("aria-label")
```

**What returns me**

> NA NA NA

**What I want to be returned**

> 3 3 2

Comment: Try this css selector instead:
`html_obj %>% html_nodes('.jUL89d') %>% html_text()`

Comment: With this code it has been achieved. Thank you very much for your input

Comment: I am going to add an official answer with some details about the exploration I did to get the correct css selector. And this way the question will appear with an answer to the rest.

Comment: Great!! post it here when this is ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are using the selector gadget to get the css selector. As you, I tried to do that, but the css the selector gadget return is not the correct one.

Inspecting the html code of the page, I realized that the correct element is contain in the tag with `class = "jUL89d y92BAb"` as you can see in this image.

[image]

This way, the code you should use is this one.

```
html_obj %>% html_nodes('.jUL89d') %>% html_text()
```

My personal recommendation for you is to always check the source code to confirm the output of the selector gadget.